# Parsing an XML file using SimpleXML, Looping based on a line item, then saving as a CSV

Tags: php, arrays, loops, csv, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an XML file, taking only certain fields, and run a foreach loop for each individual SKU and then save it as a CSV. I think I'm close but it keeps displaying either 0 or 'Array'.  Here's what I've got;

```
//Order line items
    $line_item = $order->{'line-items'}->line-item;
    $count_line_item = count($line_item);
        $item_sku = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->sku;
        $item_qty = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->quantity;
        $ship_to_email = $order->email;
        $item_price = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->price;

for($x = 0; $x <= $count_line_item; $x++) {

    $csv =
        $order_number.','.
        $first_name.','.
        $last_name.','.
        $order_date.','.
        $shipping_address1.','.
        $shipping_address2.','.
        $shipping_city.','.
        $shipping_province.','.
        $shipping_country.','.
        $shipping_zip.','.
        $shipping_phone.','.
        $item_sku.','.
        $item_qty.','.
        $ship_to_email.','.
        $item_price;

        fwrite($csv_order,$csv);

}


fclose($csv_order);

fclose($webhook);
```

Here's the XML

```
<order>
<email>jon@doe.ca</email>
<order-number type="integer">1234</order-number>
<line-items type="array">
    <line-item>
        <price type="decimal">199.99</price>
        <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
        <sku>SKU2006-001</sku>
    </line-item>
    <line-item>
        <price type="decimal">29.95</price>
        <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
        <sku>SKU2006-020</sku>
    </line-item>
</line-items>
<shipping-address type="Address">
    <address1>123 Shipping Street</address1>
    <address2 nil="true"/>
    <city>Shippington</city>
    <country>United States</country>
    <first-name>Steve</first-name>
    <last-name>Shipper</last-name>
    <phone>555-555-SHIP</phone>
    <zip>K2P0S0</zip>
    <country-code>US</country-code>
    <province-code>KY</province-code>
</shipping-address></order>
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the xml file?

Comment: I've added the code to the question @MarkShehata

I'm also not to sure only certain fields are appearing, but that can be a bonus answer!

Comment: You have a line that does nothing here: `$csv.'.csv';` Also, some broken PHP here: `$order_number.','.*$order_contact_id` - should be `$order_number.','. /* $order_contact_id` to start a comment?

Comment: @IMSoP that should be adding `$order_number.','.$first_name.','.$last_name.','.$order_date.','.$shipping_address1.','.$shipping_address2.','.$shipping_city.','.$shipping_province.','.$shipping_country.','.$shipping_zip.','.$shipping_phone.','.$item_sku.','.$item_qty.','.$ship_to_email.','.$item_price;` with .csv on the end, no?

Comment: @Newcombe Adding it to what? Just mentioning a variable or value doesn't put it anywhere.

Comment: @IMSoP I think I see what you meant and I have adjusted my code (It's still not working) but it's been updated.  I had it running through once fine, but it would only list the first SKU in the order, so I'm trying to make it run the exact same script only changing the SKU's, qty and item price for each SKU in the order. (So name, address, etc. are all staying the same)

Comment: @Newcombe The question is not showing any edits since before my last comment. Maybe it didn't save correctly?

Comment: @IMSoP This has gotten me much closer, only now it's displaying the first line twice (I've got it saving it as a .txt for reading purposes it will be a csv when it's working)